# How can I create editable sections on Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am building my first wordpress theme and I can't seem to figure out how to make another editable section. For instance, I have a hero with the `h1` of "Lorem Ipsum, Foo Bar." But would like to be able to edit this later on down the line from the admin panel.

Is this possible? I have the **[ACF(Advanced Custom Fields)](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)** plug in, but it doesn't seem to be the solution I'm looking for. I don't want a `field` as in a form on my "site preview page".

Does this make sense?

Here is how I wrote my `<h1>`

```
<h1><?php the_field('homepage_hero_text'); ?></h1>
```

Here is the field I made in ACF:
[image: ACF Custom Field]

But the field does not appear in my homepage admin panel:
[image: Field doesn't show up in admin panel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scroll to the bottom and u will be able to see "Assign this field group"

Then u can choose on which page, post, ... this field will be display.

ACF is a great solution for ur problem.

Comment: I actually just realized that the "location" feature was needed to be added. I didn't understand the "Show this field group if..." part.

I now have it working! :)

Comment: The "Show this field group if..."  permit u to display some customs fields in specific page, template, taxonomy.

Image you create a template page (ex: profil). When u assign this template to a page. ACF fields appears. And on the other pages, this ACF field doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, that was my problem. I didn't have it showing on any.

Comment: On which page do u want to display this acf field ? exactly !

Comment: I have it on Homepage now.